# Ending macro in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-project

So, I was helped with this code from Ron de Bruin from user Vityata but I am having trouble getting the macro to STOP running once it runs out of WO's and emails. If I put ' stop ' in after .send I have to click run over and over until all the emails are sent and everything is marked as 'sent', and then on the last one it won't stop running until I hit escape. I want to find a way to make the code stop running once there are no more work orders (paired with emails that haven't been sent yet) left to email out. If there is a way to also note the read receipt in a column of the 2018 worksheet that would be extremely helpful but I've been struggling. I am used to creating forms in VBA, so information going OUT has always been difficult for me to automate.

The original post is here [Original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49882296/excel-vba-to-email-each-row-based-on-criteria)

```
Sub test2()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For Each cell In Worksheets("2018").Columns("T").Cells
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then      'try with less conditions first
        With OutMail
            .To = Cells(cell.Row, "T").Value
            .Subject = "Work Order: " & Cells(cell.Row, "G").Value & " assigned"
            .Body = "Work Order: " & Cells(cell.Row, "G").Value & _
                " has been assigned to you." & _
                vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                "Region: " & Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value & vbNewLine & _
                "District: " & Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value & vbNewLine & _
                "City: " & Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value & vbNewLine & _
                "Atlas: " & Cells(cell.Row, "E").Value & vbNewLine & _
                "Notification Number: " & Cells(cell.Row, "F").Value & vbNewLine
            .ReadReceiptRequested = True
            .OriginatorDeliveryReportRequested = True
            .Send
        End With
        Cells(cell.Row, "V").Value = "sent"
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
    Next cell

'Set OutApp = Nothing                   'it will be Nothing after End Sub
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 End Sub
```

**EDIT:**
I tried to use the Do Loop function with no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you run through all cells in column T, because the range `Worksheets("2018").Columns("T").Cells` contains the complete column.

Add the following code at the beginning of your sub

```
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet


    Dim rg As Range
    Set ws = Worksheets("2018")

    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rg = Range(.Cells(1, "T"), .Cells(lastRow, "T"))
    End With
```

And change the for loop to

```
For Each cell In rg
```

`rg` only contains the filled cells of column T. In this way the code only runs through the cells which contain data.

**PS** Based on the information in the comment you would need to code your condition like that

```
If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And UCASE(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value) <> "SENT" Then
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you for the help! You wouldn't have any particular website that may give me some information on how to get the read receipt auto noted in the 2018 worksheet?

Comment: I am afraid not. I don't have a link resp. website for that.

Comment: Now, I can't get it to skip over emails already sent. Column U has the sent message, I need it to skip those. I added

        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
        Cells(cell.Row, "U").Value <> "sent" Then

Comment: There is no if condition in your code posted which skips a cell.

Comment: Hm, that must be part of the reason why it continued to run. It had no context on when to stop, nor what was to be included or excluded.

Comment: No I do not think so. The macro should have stopped after some time because at the end you only iterate through 1mio rows.